# living in specific country on tourist visa and getting citizenship

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, legal

Japan, Russia or Sweden their eligibility criteria  for citizenship are One must live in there for 5 years, would it be possible if I live there on tourist visa for 5 years am I eligible to apply for citizenship?

Comment: It's not generally possible to stay in a country for 5 years on a tourist visa.

Comment: Thanks, But if one complete eligible period in with additional visit ?

Comment: You generally have to have resident status for the specified number of years. Tourist status does not count. Plus, tourist status expires after a time. In Sweden, for example, it expires after 90 days, and the rule is such that you cannot spend more than half your time in the Schengen area.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the residency requirements are for *legal* residency. I.e.: you should be a legal permanent resident for 5 years when you apply for naturalization. This is true for Russia and the US, not familiar with Japan or Sweden - but I assume it's similar. Overstaying a tourist entry permit is not generally considered "*legal* residency" for immigration purposes.

Russia specifically has an exception for people who arrived to Russia and stayed without permanent residency before July 2002, but all of those, I assume, have naturalized already. The date is the date at which the current immigration law took effect.